# ASP.NET site on Azure Redirecting to Invalid Page

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a simple ASP.NET site hosted on Microsoft Azure App Services.  For some reason, sometimes when I visit the main url http://mysite.azurewebsites.net i get automatically redirected to a url which doesn't exist (eg http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/eQLRd/).  The following error is then returned:

"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

I checked the logs but cannot seem to find anything about this.  Has anyone experienced this behaviour?  I haven't been able to replicate this issue when working locally on IIS.

Comment: you can go to http://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net, and check your logs at `D:\home\LogFiles\eventlog.xml`

Comment: You could try to publish your website on a new Azure App Service to avoid the interference with some extensions or any other configuration you have set. Check if there is any redirected code in your asp.net site.